# Multiple annotations found at this line: - Line Breakpoint: - 1 changed line - syntax error

Tags: php

Please help me,
What is wrong at this code line:

```
$HTML_return_string .= "<option value='.$row['imie'].' '.$row['nazwisko']'"."name='$row['imie'].' '.$row['nazwisko']'>".$row['imie'].' '.$row['nazwisko']."</option>";
```

Thanks

Comment: you are mixing up double and single quotes. something like `"<option value=".$row['imie']." ".` (and so on) should do, depending on what output you want.

Comment: I would recommend that you go through [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) when dealing with string interpolation and concatenation.

Comment: If you really have to store your html into a variable, take a look at [heredoc or nowdoc strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

Comment: Still incorrect
$HTML_return_string .= '<option value=\".$row['imie'].' '.$row['nazwisko']'/".'name=/"$row['imie'].' '.$row['nazwisko']/">'.$row['imie'].' '.$row['nazwisko'].'</option>';

Answer (score 0):

You seem to misunderstand the basics about when you need to escape quotation marks and how string concatenation works.

Sometimes it's easier to first build the string in pieces using the `.=` operator:

```
$HTML_return_string .= '<option value="';
$HTML_return_string .= $row['imie'];
$HTML_return_string .= ' ';
$HTML_return_string .= $row['nazwisko'];
$HTML_return_string .= '" name="';
$HTML_return_string .= $row['imie'];
$HTML_return_string .= ' ';
$HTML_return_string .= $row['nazwisko'];
$HTML_return_string .= '">';
$HTML_return_string .= $row['imie'];
$HTML_return_string .= ' ';
$HTML_return_string .= $row['nazwisko'];
$HTML_return_string .= '</option>';
```

> Sidenote: a HTML `<option>` tag doesn't have a `name=""` attribute, but I'll leave it in anyway because I don't know if you have any Javascript code that depends on it.

Once you have that, it's easy to see how to concatenate using just a `.`. Let's start simple:

```
$HTML_return_string .= '<option value="';
$HTML_return_string .= $row['imie'] . ' ' . $row['nazwisko'];
$HTML_return_string .= '" name="';
$HTML_return_string .= $row['imie'] . ' ' . $row['nazwisko'];
$HTML_return_string .= '">';
$HTML_return_string .= $row['imie'] . ' ' . $row['nazwisko'];
$HTML_return_string .= '</option>';
```

You should be able to put the rest together yourself, but if you feel like cheating:

```
$HTML_return_string .= '<option value="' . $row['imie'] . ' ' . $row['nazwisko'] . '" name="' . $row['imie'] . ' ' . $row['nazwisko'] . '">' . $row['imie'] . ' ' . $row['nazwisko'] . '</option>';
```